# why the session id changed?

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, session, cookies

Q1 , we recently experiencing issues around ajax and shopping cart,scenario for Q1 is  :

we have 2 web sites, 123.abc.com and www.abc.com ,we keep cart on both sites synced through proxied ajax call.which www.abc.com is the main site for checkout.steps to replicate the Q1 issue are

```
1)desktop,open IE and go to www.abc.com ,response has set cookie sid=xyz1 domain=.abc.com path=/
2)then search something by typing some key words. it will pass keywords to 123.abc.com in URL and jump to 123.abc.com to show the results,response has set cookie sid=xyz2 without domain info
3)after dom is ready, there is an ajax call proxied to www.abc.com to get cart content, this request has sid=xyz2 in header to 123.abc.com and the response has setcookie sid=xyz2 domain=.abc.com path=/ 
4)randomly pick some products and click add to cart,then js will make ajax call to 123.abc.com server,that server proxy the call to www.abc.com . response to ajax carries setcookie sid=xyz2 domain=.abc.com path=/  
5)click a link in search result page and navigate back to www.abc.com, browser will use sid=xyz1 which lost the cart info
```

above happends in office with IE11 and I am in intranet.staff from 123.abc.com complained www.abc.com overwrites their sid cookie in some proxied document ready ajax response from www.abc.com for getting current cart content on www.abc.com

123.abc.com and www.abc.com are hosted with different companies and servers

I then install fiddler and open it to monitor the traffic from IE11, problem is gone, I can see the cart on www.abc.com
FF and chrome are fine(if www.abc.com overwirtes sid cookie , then how/why FF and chrome stays good ?)

is this an issue with intranet mixed with different cookie management for browsers?

Q2 , anothere problem is with mobile chrome.

```
1)open www.ab.com on mobile in chrome, it will be redirected to 123.abc.com/m/
2)add something to cart while still on 123.abc.com/m/ 
3)navigatte back to www.abc.com to checkout. cart is empty
```

above happends with office wifi . if I switch mobile network to 4G, cart is empty (strange)
FF and opera works fine with 4G and wifi 
is it having something to do with browser cookie manager implementation ? or an issue mixed with network constraint?

thanks in advance

Comment: turns out it is the security policy making noise. add to trusted site.all done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out it is the security policy making noise. add to trusted site.all done.